# How can I create a WPA2 Wi-Fi hotspot with NetworkManager?

Tags: wifi, bash, hotspot, wpa, networkmanager

I have a project for which I'd like to automate configuring the network settings on a Raspberry Pi. I can create a WPA1 hotspot very easily with the following bash one-liner.

```
nmcli connection add \
    con-name wifi_hotspot \
    ifname wlan0 \
    type wifi \
    autoconnect no \
    ipv4.method shared \
    802-11-wireless.band bg \
    802-11-wireless.mode ap \
    802-11-wireless.ssid "wifi_hotspot" \
    802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk \
    802-11-wireless-security.psk "rubberbabybuggybumpers" \
    802-11-wireless.hidden yes
```

It seems like the NetworkManager parameter `802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt` is missing an option to specify WPA2 over WPA1.

Is there a way to create a hotspot with WPA2 encryption?

## EDIT 1:

I found that specifying `802-11-wireless-security.proto rsn` enables WPA2, but also leaves WPA1 enabled. How can I enable only WPA2?

Comment: What operating system do you use? NetworkManager isn't supported by Raspbian.

Comment: I am using headless Raspbian Stretch. Could you possibly point me to documentation that NetworkManager isn't supported? It works great except for this one issue I'm having.

Comment: **NetworkManager** isn't part of any Raspbian image. You will not find a link that tell you what is **not** supported. You only will find links telling you what is supported and Raspbian uses **dhcpcd**: [Another Raspbian Desktop User Interface Update](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-raspbian-desktop-user-interface-update/). And no, NetworkManager isn't working great on Raspbian as you see.